# is redis on node.js synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis

```
subscriber.subscribe('CHANNEL');

subscriber.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    // If I do multiple jobs, say multiple db inserts 
    insert1;
    insert2;
}
```

Is the following a possible sequence of action?

```
insert1
insert1
insert2
insert2
```

or is it guaranteed to be the following sequences all the time?

```
insert1
insert2
insert1
insert2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use the node_redis client, yes, it is asynchronous.

Subscribers need their own Redis connection anyway, so even if the insert1 and insert2 operations target the same Redis instance, you have no guarantee about the sequence of actions.

Note that in practice, you will not code:

```
insert1;
insert2;
```

but rather:

```
insert1( function() {
    insert2( function() {
        callback()
    });
});
```

... at least if you need to check whether the inserts went fine.

Comment: Thank you. can you take my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33954599/node-redis-variables-are-shared-between-clients ? (step 2 question)

Comment: does `insert1; insert2;` block IO? or it works on a separate thread in redis module?

Comment: It does not block, and it does not work in a separate thread.insert 1; insert 2 ; will just send the two inserts without waiting for completion,